# is it possible to store ToolStripItemCollection in an SQL table?

Tags: c#

I need to share the same ToolStripItemCollection between to .exe

I thought of save the ToolStripItemCollection into an SQL table, so it can be retrieved by both .exe

Is it possible? If so, how can I achieve this and what would be the SQL table datatype

Many thanks.

Comment: You can't share the same ToolStripItemCollection between too .exe, but you can save the state of one instance in memory and write it to SQL, and then generate a _new_ ToolStripItemCollection instance base on the retrieved one from SQL. This is a bad idea to save it to sql.

Answer (score 1):

You can Serialize and store in the database. But that's not a good way of doing that (at least not the best way).

I think you should store all the custom information(Text, icon, etc) that you want to recreate them rather than storing ToolStripItemCollection itself.